# How to rotate the uv in the direction of the mesh

Tags: 3d

The question has been tormenting for several days, unfortunately I could not find a solution. The magic poke method, too, did not bring results.

You need to create your own LineRenderer, because Unity does not correctly display the grid of lines during sharp turns, and adding auxiliary points does not always bring good results. In general, I began to comprehend the knowledge about MESH!

I created a test scene and made 3 squares:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgLan.png)

Denoted the UV coordinates.
The topmost square was specially made slightly to the left to check how the line will rotate in the direction of the vertices.
I added the rotation formula iiiii in the code - unfortunately it didn 't work the way I intended .

The picture itself turned a little, but for some reason the vertices themselves shifted to UV.

Perhaps I am completely wrong in implementing my plans.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKE7B.png)

The material itself is created through Shader Graphics.

Perhaps there is a very simple option, but I can not understand it in any way.

I ask for your help!
And I apologize for the English!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYAz8.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to assign a different UV coordinates. This solved my question. Now there is another problem. When rotating, the texture of the material is stretched

Apparently the problem is due to the fact that the texture itself stretches along the length of the mesh. I need to somehow set the mode in shader graph to repeat, not stretch

[UV coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umHbW.jpg)

[Shader graph - settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYlb8.jpg)

[New result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb8kD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Everything turned out with God's help!

The texture was twisted and stretched, because I set the initial vertices of the next polygon to the final vertices of the previous one.
The solution came unexpectedly and accidentally, to set separate vertices for each polygon. At the same time, the texture that is superimposed on the entire mesh is displayed without errors, even with sharp turns

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkZi4.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7x5G.jpg)

[Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jODnf.jpg)

[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHt3Y.jpg)

Comment: Code is best with it is `code`, not a picture of code. You create a code block by putting three backticks ``` above your block of code, paste it in, then three backticks ``` to close the section of code. It will look better and be usable by others. Also, `// comments` should be in English on this site, and you should select an appropriate 'tag' for both the language, presumably `c++` and the problem type if available `mesh` perhaps. Welcome to Stackoverflow.